# ImageMagick error rangecheck in --run-- when using convert on multi layered pdf documents

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, ghostscript

I'm  trying to convert a pdf document that contains multiple layers to a .jpg image. But it gives me an error. Please see below:

with this command:

```
convert test.pdf test.jpeg
```

The result:

```
Error: /rangecheck in --run--
Operand stack:
   --dict:7/16(L)--   Im0   0.0   --nostringval--   true   2292   0   0   1
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1878   1   3   %oparray_pop   1877   1   3   %oparray_pop   1861   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   1   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1162/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:108/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:290/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)--   --dict:6/8(L)--   --dict:21/40(L)--   --dict:5/5(L)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:5/5(L)--   --dict:8/15(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 8.71: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
convert: Postscript delegate failed `test.pdf': ACzp.cache @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/638.
convert: missing an image filename `test.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2940.
```

i also tried

```
convert --flatten test.pdf test.jpeg
```

but also no luck.

Can please anyone help me with this problem im stuck on the moment?

Comment: Looks like Ghostscript is unable to render the PDF. Try updating the binary as version 8.71 is almost 10 years old.